# Change the value of a field depending on the selection of another

Tags: forms

I need to change the value of a field based on the selection of another.   I also don't want the user to have the ability to change this value.  I tried using `#disabled = true`, but the values don't *save*, and the same with `#access`.

I'm not sure how to go about this?  `#disabled` seems to stop values from being saved - what alternatives are there?

This surely can't be unique, I know often date fields do this.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the element to a `value` type might be easiest:

```
// In a form alter hook.
$form['field_foo'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#type'] = 'value';
$form['field_foo'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#value'] = 'some static value';
```

Answer (score 0):

disabled fields by default are not submitted with the form not only within Drupal/PHP but in general those fields are not passed to the processor method. you can read about that in more details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12).

@Clive suggested right answer, but other option would be to use form validation handler to assign the value before it is submitted.

```
//in form hook alter
form['#validate'][] = 'my_validation_handler';
```

and then:

```
function my_validation_handler($form, &$form_state) {
    //could be target_id instead of 'value' depending on the field type
    $form_state['values']['my_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'my_value'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't able to get this working with #disabled, but it did handle cases where the select box value had been changed (and I used validate to reset).  Thanks!